# Laravel 5.0 - Where to use bindings from Service Providers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

In my `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` I did create the method `register`:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bindShared('JustTesting', function($app)
    {
        die('got here!');
        // return new MyClass;
    });
}
```

Where should I use that? I did create a method in `App\Http\Controllers\HomeController`:

```
/**
 * ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 53:
 * Class JustTesting does not exist
 *
 * @Get("/test")
 */
public function test(\JustTesting $test) {
    echo 'Hello';
}
```

But didn't works, I also can't use $this->app->make('JustTesting');

It works if I do as the code below, but I would like to Inject into controller.

```
/**
 * "got here!"
 *
 * @Get("/test")
 */
public function test() {
    \App::make('JustTesting');
}
```

How should I bind like I want to? And if it's not allowed, why should I use the `bindShared` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though your first controller route is throwing a ReflectionException because the object `JustTesting` does not actually exist at the time the IoC Container is attempting to resolve it.

Also, you should code to an interface. Binding `JustTestingInterace` to `MyClass` would be so that Laravel knows "Ok, when an implementation of `JustTestingInterface` is requested, I should resolve it to `MyClass`."

**RouteServiceProvider.php:**

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bindShared('App\Namespace\JustTestingInterface', 'App\Namespace\MyClass');
}
```

**Inside of your controller:**

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Namespace\JustTestingInterface;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function test(JustTestingInterface $test)
    {
        // This should work
        dd($test);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use `MyClass` because it can change to another class in future (e.g. another vendor, but implementing the same interface). So could I use `... test(JustTestingInterface $test)` in my controller? Then it should be resolved to `MyClass` (or another class that I want to bind with `bindShared` method)

Comment: @GiovanneAfonso I fixed my original code which was incorrect.... `JustTestingInterface` should be an interface that is implemented by `MyClass`. Then you would bind `JustTestingInterface` to `MyClass` so that Laravel will know to use `MyClass` when an implementation of `JustTestingInterface` is requested.